# List comprehension flat list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, list-comprehension, python-itertools

I have the following toy function:

```
def foo(a):
    return [a+5]
```

And I am running the following code:

```
my_lst = [foo(x) for x in range(10) if x%2 == 0]
```

Getting:

```
[[5], [7], [9], [11], [13]]
```

But need:

```
[5,7,9,11,13]
```

But I want to get a plain list, not a list of lists.
How can I do it without `itertools.chain.from_iterable(my_lst)` but with list comprehension?
What is the best practice? itertools or list comprehension in this case?

Please advice.

I have tried:

```
[j[0] for j in [foo(x) for x in range(10) if x%2 == 0]]
```

Should I do it like this or there is a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With list comprehension, it's done using two `for` loops:

```
my_lst = [subx for x in range(10) if x%2 == 0 for subx in foo(x)]
```

Also if you have a list of lists of one elements, you can "transpose" after the fact the list using `zip`:

```
bad_lst = [foo(x) for x in range(10) if x%2 == 0]
[my_lst] = zip(*bad_lst)
```

Or you can "transpose" using a list comprehension combined with list unpacking as well if you truly want a list as output and not a tuple:

```
bad_lst = [foo(x) for x in range(10) if x%2 == 0]
my_lst = [x for [x] in bad_lst]
```

Comment: itertools.chain is probably more efficient though.

Comment: Please explain the trick with zip and what is transpose here?

Comment: And what does the [my_lst] means? @Laerne

Comment: Zip takes a tuple of sequences and return a sequence of tuple. E.g. `list(zip([0,1,2], ['a', 'b', 'c']))` will be `[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]`. In other words, zip converts `n` sequences of length `m` to `m` sequences of length `n`. You have 2D list `bad_lst` of size `n`×`1`. Using the `*` notation (see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), you pass along all the `n` sequences of `bad_lst` with length `1` to zip, which will spit out `1` sequence of length `n` with every elements.

Comment: `[my_lst]` is list unpacking: If on the right hand side you have a list with one element `e`, this will set `my_lst` to e. If the list has 0 or more than 2 elements, this will fails. Likewise, if the right hand side had 3 elements, you could write `[e1, e2, e3] = right_hand_side` and have `e1` the first element, `e2` the second, `e3` the third.

Comment: So in this case we have a list with one element - tuple created by ```zip```. So we transfer this tuple to ```my_lst``` that makes it a list? @laerne

Comment: If you really want a list, not a tuple, you can use `my_lst = list(zip(*bad_lst)[0])`, but it begins to be somewhat messy to read: use a list comprehension then, I've added it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

alternatively to Laernes answer, you can also use `itertools` as :

```
list(itertools.chain(*[foo(x) for x in range(10) if x%2 == 0]))
```

or

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([foo(x) for x in range(10) if x%2 == 0]))
```

More options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-do-i-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists):

Answer (score -1):

Your function should return a number, not a list:

```
def foo(a):
    return a+5
```

Comment: My function is just an example. In my program I have a lot of functions and the result is list of lists I want to flatten.

Comment: Ok, I understand now.   Your list comprehension `[j[0] for j in [foo(x) for x in range(10) if x%2 == 0]] ` works fine.   I see no reason to prefer something else.